# Cannot set or enable breakpoints in Visual Studio Code when debugging C++ with GDB

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gdb

When debugging my C++ program with GDB on Ubuntu, I can set/disable/enable breakpoints after my program is running, no issue. But in Visual Studio Code, I can only set a breakpoint **befor**e program is launched, and after program starts, I cannot add new breakpoints, nor can I re-eanable a breakpoint once I disable it. Does anyone encounter this situation? Thanks!

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. Include the version of your C/C++ extension, the version of your G++ installation, and a [mre] including a basic program, where to attempt to place the breakpoint, and the launch config.